# Show that a subspace is proper dense in $l^1$ sequence space. L^1 space.

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let *Y* = $L^1 $($\mu$) where $\mu$ is counting measure on **N**.

Let *X* = {$f$ $\in$ *Y* : $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}$ *n*|$f(n)$|<$\infty$}, equipped with the $L^1$ norm.

Show that *X* is a proper dense subspace of *Y*.

---

I don't know how to show that *X* is dense in *Y*.

I was thinking about constructing a sequence in *Y* so that every convergent sequence in *X* converges to the sequence in *Y*.

But then I think there might be another way to show denseness of *X*.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Think about sequences that are $0$ except for finitely many terms.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e_i :\mathbb N\to\mathbb R$ defined as
$$
e_i(j)=\left\{\begin{array}{lll} 1 &\text{if}&i=j,\\ 0 &\text{if}&i\ne j.\end{array}\right.
$$
Then $e_i\in X$. If $f\in Y$, then setting 
$$
f_n=\sum_{i=1}^n f(i)\, e_i\in X,
$$
we observe that
$$
\|f-f_n\|_{L^1}=\sum_{i>n}\lvert\,f(i)\rvert.
$$
Clearly, the right hand side of the above tends to zero, as $n\to\infty$, and hence $f_n\to f$ in $L^1(\mu)$.